# Create a regular expression for this string: Dec 3, 2005

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to create a regular expression for detecting the publication date for a book in Amazon. I'm extracting the data for all items and I want to find a publication's date. All of these has this structure:
                            `Month day, year.`

The month is only represented by 3 chars, and the day could have one or two numbers (e.g Dec 5, 2011 or Dec 22, 2011). The year always have 4 numbers.

How I can do a regex in JavaScript to find this?

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Can you show us what you tried or are you just trying to get people to do the work for you?

Comment: @BillCriswell I don't want that anyone do the work for me, I just need help because I don't know much about regular expressions.

Comment: @Noelia Are you sure you want a regular expression, and not a date parsing utility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
var myregexp = /([a-z]{3}) (\d{1,2}), (\d{4})/i;
var match = myregexp.exec(subject);
if (match != null) {
    result = match[1];
}
```

will get you going. `match[1]` hold months, `match[2]` days and `match[3]` years.

I will omit explaining the regex. I leave it as an exercise to you. You should visit the infamous regex tutorial **[here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)**.

Comment: yes, I'm reading this tutorial when I have time, but I need to do this asap, or I'm dead jajaja

Comment: The snag here, of course, is that the above regex will match *any* three characters, not just month names. "Fus 12, 1994" is as valid as "Dec 12, 1994".

Comment: @kojiro It also matches 0000 as valid year, like yours. OP didn't mention validating a date, rather matching it.

Comment: @FailedDev True, OP only hinted at it ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
/(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec) \d{1,2}, \d{4}/i
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what you pretend to do with it (extract something, parse part of it, …) so here is one to simply "match" these dates:

```
/\b\w{3} [1-3]?[0-9], \d{4}/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var date = "Dec 22, 2011";
var match = date.match(/(\w+)\s(\d+),\s(\d+)/);
// match[1] == "Dec"
// match[2] == "22"
// match[3] == "2011"
```

Note that this may fail if the format ever changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Apr|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s{1}\d{1,2},\s{1}\d{4}$
```

OR

```
/^(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Apr|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s{1}\d{1,2},\s{1}\d{4}$/gim
```

**Here:** 
*g - Global* 
*i - IgnoreCase* 
*m - Multiline*

You can try validating the RegExp through the **[gskinner](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)**